# One out of four holes in this bracket miss the stud - what would you do?

Tags: drywall, hanging, drywall-anchor

I want to mount some mesh on the wall in my kitchen to increase pan/utensil storage space. The mesh I have acquired isn't too heavy but when laden it will.

It's designed to slot and hang on grooves off four brackets. The brackets are diamond shaped and have four holes for screws in each corner of the diamond.

The issue is that the stud behind the drywall isn't wide enough to position the bracket over it and all four screws hit a solid enough bit of wood. Stud is as wide as the pencil marks in pic.

So as far as I can fathom, I either:

1. Only use the top and bottom screw holes into the stud on each
   bracket
2. Offset the bracket slightly from the stud and only use
   each top, bottom and only one side hole/
3. Same as b) but add a drywall anchor for other side hole that would miss the stud
4. Avoid the stud altogether and use drywall anchors for all brackets
5. An alternative elegant solution suggested by this wonderful community!

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Two screws (of adequate length) are plenty here. You won't pull them out with a dozen cast iron pans.

Use the largest screws that comfortably fit the holes and penetrate framing lumber about 1-1/4". Pilot just a bit smaller than the screw shank.

I would not use drywall anchors. They're unnecessary and likely to either hold the bracket off the wall or show around the bracket.

If you want to install screws for appearance, just run them into the drywall very gently. Don't strip them. They'll stay put.

Comment: +1 Adequate length is important.  If OP doesn't know what's behind the wall then 1-1/2" screws should be the maximum to avoid hitting wires that may cross the stud.  If OP is certain there is no electricity or plumbing running across that stud then 2-1/2" or even 3" screws would give a better hold.  In that case, toenailing 3" screws from the side holes towards the stud could probably work too and add a bit of extra hold.

Comment: You should never use a screw or nail longer than 1-1/4" into any stud so 1-1/2" is the maximum length with 1/2" drywall but you should never recommend more than that and there really is no reason for it anyway.  With the type of load on this hook a 1-1/2" screw would shear before it pulls out anyway.

Comment: I disagree. It's usually fairly easy to determine whether there will be plumbing in a wall, and electrical is also fairly predictably run. And screws rarely shear. They can _twist_ off, but they don't often break due to load. You can pull a 3" deck screw out with a hammer.

Comment: @isherwood sure you can pull them straight out but this load will be pulling down on them.  The sheer force of most screws is anywhere from 200-300 lbs I bet you with 2 1" screws in this you could easily hang 400 lbs from that hook without much issue.  Also it is not fairly easy to determine where plumbing or electrical is.  Chicken sticks lie and companies that do installs for a living will hit both plumbing and electrical a few times a year.  It's a pretty universal rule to never use anything over 1-1/4" because that is where the code requires these things to be set back.

Comment: Also you would likely snap the head off a 3" deck screw before it pulled out depending on how rotten the wood is.  It would take around 330lbs of force and assuming your hammer is 1' long you would have to apply 165lbs to the end of the hammer to accomplish that.

Comment: Well so have I and I have seen the opposite of you so our experiences cancel each other out.  But you can easily google "do screws resist sheer force?", "maximum length of screw/nail in drywall?", "strength required to pull out a screw?", etc

Answer (score 11):

Centre the top and bottom holes to the stud and use drywall anchors for the other two if needed.

A stud is only an inch and a half  wide, A screw right at the edge of a stud not much use.

Could try to angle the two side screws towards the stud centre for greater holding power.